# ReferenceError: addPpl is not defined

Tags: javascript

I've looked through the codes but i can't find the error.

Called it in a button
`input name="Add People" type="button" onclick="addPpl()" value="Add People" />`

> ReferenceError: addPpl is not defined

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>        
    <input name="Add People" type="button" onclick="addPpl()" value="Add People" />
    <TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=6 id="myTable">
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" type="text/jquery" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">

        function addPpl() {
            var table = $("#myTable");
            var tr = $("<tr />");
            for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
                i++
                var td = $('"<td width="22" align="left" valign="top">' + i + '</td><td width="344" align="left" valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">  </td></tr>"');

                var inp = $('"<input name="people_no"' + i + ' type="text" id="people_no"' + i + ' value="-" size="40" /></font>"');
                td.append(inp);

                if (i < 5) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                        i++
                        var td = $('"<td width="25" align="left" valign="top">' + i + '</td><td width="343" align="left" valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">  </td></tr>"');

                        var inp = $('"<input name="people_no"' + i + ' type="text" id="people_"' + i + ' value="-" size="40" /></font> "');
                        td.append(inp);
                    }
                    tr.append(td);
                }
                table.append(tr);
            }
        }

        </SCRIPT>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Where do you call this function?

Comment: Problem us where are you calling this function?

Comment: outside of the table 

<input name="Add People" type="button" onclick="javascript:addPpl()" value="Add People" />

Comment: And where is the function defined? Please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. (See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `onclick="javascript:addPpl()"` is incorrect. Just use `addPpl()`. The `javascript:` keyword is links.

Comment: @Mouser tried it doesnt work

Comment: please post your HTML. Ran your code through my webpage. Renders ok. So there's no error in there on parsing.

Comment: Get rid of inline event handlers. Instead, add the event handler using `addEventListener` just after declaring your function. This way, the function won't be undefined.

Comment: @Mouser posted my html

Comment: **"If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI"**. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html so follow the answer suggested by @Mouser and move your script code to another <script> tag without src.

Comment: Also be consistent with your for lusses. Put the add index (`i++`) into your for lus like you did with `for(var k=0; k<1; k++ )`

Comment: Last issue I'm going to point out: In you second loop you again use `i++`. This will run the first loop faster than you might want. It now adds `2` per cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a script element.

This script element loads your jQuery:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" type="text/jquery" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

But after that you should open another script element `script`

You cannot put code into a script element that has a `src` attribute. That script element gets filled with the code from the source. If you want to put code on your page use a script element without a `src`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //your code goes here
</script>
```

Also you need to close the jQuery script element .

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" type="text/jquery" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: As Konkked posted, your script is in your table tag. It should be a good idea to move it out of there, because the script now becomes a child element of the table. If the `innerHTML` of the table gets changed the script tag, including it's functions, disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You have double `"` on the inside of the beginning of your strings, see edited example below.

Also includes a few other changes for the following reasons

It looks like you have the script in the table tag, put the script into the head portion of the document, and you are using the type `text/jquery` when you should be using `text\javascript`, change those two issues and see if that resolves the issue

Also as noted by [@Mouser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364303/mouser) you need a separate tag for the jQuery reference

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addPpl(){

                var table = $("#myTable");

                    var tr = $("<tr />");
                        for(var i=0; i<5; ){
                        i++
                            var td = $('<td width="22" align="left" valign="top">' + i + '</td><td width="344" align="left" valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">  </td></tr>');

                    var inp = $('<input name="people_no"'+i+' type="text" id="people_no"'+i+' value="-" size="40" /></font>');
                    td.append(inp);

                    if(i<5) {

                        for( var k=0; k<1; k++ ){
                            i++
                            var td = $('<td width="25" align="left" valign="top">' + i + '</td><td width="343" align="left" valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">  </td></tr>');
                            var inp = $('<input name="people_no"'+i+' type="text" id="people_"'+i+' value="-" size="40" /></font>');
                            td.append(inp);
                        }
                        tr.append(td);
                    }
                table.append(tr);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <input name="Add People" type="button" onclick="addPpl()" value="Add People" />
        <table BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=6 id="myTable"></table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Konkked This won't work, see my answer. The error is still there.

Comment: @Mouser it was the quote on the inside of the strings that was causing the problem

Comment: @konkked You tried to fixed his entire code, I only addressed the question, why is `addPpl` undefined and pointed out some other problems with the code in the comments. The quotes are a good call. But even your updated code has still issues.

Comment: @Mouser, I fixed all of the problems I was getting from my browser and things that were absolutely incorrect (i.e. having the `type` attribute of the script as `text/jquery`, the original code had lots of issues, was trying to figure out what was wrong, when I found the problem this was the code I was left with, didn't see the purpose of leaving out information if it would help the op